# Java frame for displaying always fullscreen game?

Tags: java, swing

Currently I have JFrame that is always set to fullscreen, JPanel with a resolution that can be changed and a BufferedImage which is drawn onto the JPanel and is a fixed resolution of my game. I feel like this is very inefficient since there can be like three different resolutions, the fullscreen used for the JFrame being a screen resolution, a custom resolution for JPanel set by the user and the game's resolution could be different to both where I would be resizing twice before drawing.

How do modern games like Battlefield allow you to change resolution, they're always fullscreen and they're not just resizing in the window when they resize since I have a dual screen with one a TV and it actually shows me changed resolution due to changing the resolution of the game eventhough my TV can take the max of 1920 x 1080 but it's still fullscreen? All I need is really drawing to pixels, I don't even need adding buttons from swing or anything like that, I'll do that myself. My game is should always be fullscreen. I've been making my game and I'm really comfortable with using JFrame and JPanel but I really want to switch to something else if it's more efficient. What do you think I could do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
```

or

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
gd.setFullScreenWindow(app);
```

Also take a look at this post:

[In JAVA, changing resolution with setDisplayMode for fullscreen application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812268/in-java-changing-resolution-with-setdisplaymode-for-fullscreen-application)

Answer (score 0):

Rendering to a BufferedImage of *fixed* size is somewhat defeating the purpose, unless you explicitly *want scaling* (e.g. because you can't render the full res fast enough).

All you need to do is resize your back buffer when the frame size changes (and render into it according to its current size, of course).

You can detect the changes easily by using either a WindowListener attached to the JFrame, or a ComponentListener attached to the contained panel. For flexibility, I personally would prefer the ComponentListener on the panel, because that enables you to use the same panel and listener for either windowed or full screen mode. Be cautious though that the listener will be called on the Swing event dispatch thread, so depending on the threading architecture of your game you may need some thread synchronization to communicate the change safely.

Answer (score 0):

The way games like battlefield do it is with 3D world coordinates that are independent of the screen resolution using OpenGL or DirectX. Developers feed world coordinates into a rendering engine that then converts to screen coordinates. This is done with whatever the current screen resolution is set to. You will notice though that the HUD size will change depending on your selection of resolution. This is because the HUD is usually a 2D construct that is tied directly to screen coordinates. If you want to do some 3D stuff I would recommend [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/). Your only option with Swing is to look into using AffineTransform to scale your display. This however is inefficient compared to 3D and could be slower than you would desire.

Comment: I'm only talking about how they set up the fullscreen window for the game not the actually game content and the rendering parts. Just how they set up the frame, I know they use some language of Microsoft C but how would it be like in Java

Comment: Not much different that what you need to do in Java. You detect available display modes and let the user select. Then they attach the 3D context to surface and go to town.