# Full screen JFrame doesn't cover screen

Tags: java, swing

I have searched for a solution to this but can't seem to find it. 
If this has already been answered please link me to the answer. I am creating a JFrame setting it to full screen and changing the display mode. 
This all works fine and the display mode is supported by my graphics card (I have already checked) so that is all ok. I am adding a canvas to the JFrame, creating a buffer strategy and using it to draw custom graphics to the screen. The issue is that when the display mode changes and the JFrame enters full screen mode it doesn't cover the full screen. This doesn't make sense as the display mode is 1024 x 768 and the canvas size is also 1024 x 768. 
Instead the canvas sits in the top left corner of the screen in the same proportions as when the display mode wasn't changed. Furthermore, the graphics the don't draw properly. Everything works fine when I don't try to change the display mode and set full screen.

Here are the three lines of code that sets everything to full screen.

```
gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
    gd.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1024,768,32,48));
```

I am running windows 10 and my normal display mode is 3840x2160. Here is a screenshot of what happens when I run the code.

[image: screen shot]

Although it doesnt look like it the display mode definitely changes as the screen goes black and then the screen becomes smaller and more blured.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812268/in-java-changing-resolution-with-setdisplaymode-for-fullscreen-application)? Specifically: *The display mode* ***must be one of the display modes returned by getDisplayModes()***

Comment: Yes, the display mode is in that list.

Comment: Can't you just use: `jframe.setExtendedState(jframe.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`?

Comment: That works in getting the frame to cover the screen but the canvas isn't stretching out. I want the canvas to cover the full screen.

Comment: @DechlanVictory I tried that code on my PC with one on my supported modes and it worked. Can you post the output of `getDisplayModes()`? `for(DisplayMode dm : gd.getDisplayModes()) { System.out.printf("[width: %d, height: %d, bitDepth: %d, refreshRate: %d]%n", dm.getWidth(), dm.getHeight(), dm.getBitDepth(), dm.getRefreshRate()); }`

Comment: Welcome to SO. 

"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include .... the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." See: [mcve]

Comment: `but the canvas isn't stretching out.` - that is a problem with your application code, not the setExtendedState(...) method. `I am adding a canvas to the JFrame, creating a buffer strategy and using it to draw custom graphics to the screen` - why are you using a Canvas, that is an AWT component. Use a JPanel, Swing is double buffered by default.

Comment: @BackSlash Here is part of the output.
[width: 800, height: 600, bitDepth: 32, refreshRate: 48]
[width: 1024, height: 768, bitDepth: 32, refreshRate: 48]
[width: 1024, height: 768, bitDepth: 32, refreshRate: 48]
[width: 1024, height: 768, bitDepth: 32, refreshRate: 48]
[width: 1152, height: 864, bitDepth: 32, refreshRate: 48]
[width: 1152, height: 864, bitDepth: 32, refreshRate: 48]

Comment: @camickr Ok so maybe I am misunderstanding how a display mode works. Basically in your opinion if I set the display mode to 1024x768 and I have a canvas with size 1024x768, should the canvas cover the whole screen? This is the logic that I am following in my program. As for the JPanel I will take note of that for next time.

Comment: I'm saying when you use Swing you should be using layout managers. There is no reason to set the size of a component. By default a JFrame uses a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the CENTER of the frame then the component will take all the available space in the frame after accounting for the borders and title bar etc. So the component will adjust to whatever size the frame is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to maximize the window using setExtendedState? (Like in below example)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MaximizedFrame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Fullscreen != maximized

Comment: That works better, in that the whole screen is now covered, but the canvas is still in the upper left corner when I want the canvas to cover the whole screen.